# SSAS attribute hierarchy not usable as row label in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, ssas-2012

I have a Time dimension that has Fiscal and Gregorian hierarchies that I'm trying to use (either, not both) as row labels in an Excel pivot table. I can add either as a filter, but Excel will not allow me to drag them into the row labels box. Each time I do, Excel refreshes without placing the hierarchy in the row labels.

I tried dropping and rebuilding the dimension in BIDS, but there has been no effect on the end result in Excel. Other dimensions with hierarchies seem to work fine as row labels and filters, and the Time dimension members that are not in hierarchies work fine as row labels as well. My cube is built in SSAS 2012 and I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: Thanks Corley. I've found many solutions on this site to issues I've faced in BI and C# development, but this is my first time asking a new question. I'm grateful for this site's content and any solutions I may find to my current issue.

Comment: I've been working with Microsoft to get the issue fixed. Strangely enough, there is no such problem with Excel 2013, so that is what my customers have migrated to.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Office to 2013. The issue does not occur when accessing a cube built in SSAS 2012 from Excel 2013.